# Working on UK freelance contract for a UK company while travelling

Tags: taxes

I'm currently residing in UK and working as an employee for a UK company. I'll soon move out of UK and travel around the world, while working on freelance contract for UK companies.

This is the first time I'll do freelance contract and I'll be abroad. What is the best way to approach this?

- Do I start a limited company or should I be sole trader? Do I invoice the companies as a separate company or as a self employed person?
- Where do I pay my taxes if my earnings are coming from UK but I'm not residing there?
- Where do I get the accountant? Or do I need one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on the amount of money involved. There is no need to set up a LTD company just for going overseas. You also have to be overseas quite a large chunk of the year to not be considered resident any more. If I were you, and I assume you are a sole trader, I would continue to do whatever you have been doing up to now, but if you want to see if there are any tax benefits, you need to speak to an accountant about your entire personal and financial situation. My only advice would be to pay for the advice, otherwise you are likely to not get good advice, but a sales pitch.